# Looking for a children show with talking dogs

Tags: story-identification, tv

When I was a child, around fifteen years ago give or take (late 90s, early 00s), there was a TV show that aired on TV (could have been Disney Channel, or another channel airing content for children) with live dogs talking [so not a cartoon/animation, but live content], and, I believe, having jobs or so.

I do remember one of them being a Dobermann, and I think he had an important job such as a Boss of something (he could even have worn clothes but I am not sure about that). I don't believe he was the main character, though.
My sister and I have been looking for that show's title for years, but we remember so little it's pretty hard to find it. There is a possibility it is a movie rather than a show, but I'm pretty sure it is a show.

I watched this on French television but this was definitely originally a US show.

Comment: This isn't a lot to get started. But is the show: **Allô maman, c'est Noël?**. The original English title is: **Look Who's Talking Now**.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but that's more like 20 years ago. You're getting old. :)

Comment: More to the point, was this live action or animation?

Comment: I perhaps should have said that it wasn't animation, rather than not a cartoon, will edit to clarify! [when doing my really bad maths I assumed I was somewhere younger than ten which was 15 years ago, but numbers aren't my forte apparently :') ]

Comment: I am also wondering this American talking dog actors' tv series. I also remember that some dogs wore clothes and even the glasses, and when they were talking, their mouth moves were like barking. I remember the dogs were acting inside the house, and one was german shepherd whose wife was a poodle, maybe? Can't find info on what was the title. I think it was from late '80s to early '90s.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this one: *[100 Deeds for Eddie McDowd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_Deeds_for_Eddie_McDowd)*

A boy is changed to a dog and won't become human again until he does 100 good deeds.

> *100 Deeds for Eddie McDowd* is an American television sitcom created for Nickelodeon by Steven H. Berman, Mitchel Katlin, and Nat Bernstein. The series ran for three seasons - from October 16, 1999 until April 21, 2002.
>
> Eddie McDowd (Jason Dohring) is considered to be a schoolyard bully by his peers. McDowd considers himself very attractive and powerful and so he bullies others without mercy. One day, while bullying a kid after school, he is caught by a kind of mystical man. He tells McDowd that due to his bullying he will be punished for his wrongdoings by living life as a dog, and that in order to be restored as a human he has to do 100 good deeds for others. Besides The Drifter, the only one who can hear him talk is Justin Taylor, the last kid he bullied. At first the two are firmly against the idea, but McDowd realizes that he must work alongside Justin and his family to finish his good deeds. Every time Eddie performs a good deed the Drifter appears with a creatively presented number stating the remaining deeds he has left. Occasionally when Eddie misbehaves the Drifter takes away one of his deeds. The story has no ending as the series was cancelled before a final resolution could be made.

In France, this show could be seen on France 3 in 1999 and on France 5 in 2010.

Comment: In France, this show could be seen on France 3 in 1999 and on France 5 in 2010.

Comment: @Lyzvaleska you or jo1storm can [edit] that into the answer, that's valuable information.

Comment: This might be the one. I'm still confused as I pretty vividly remember that dobermann (the only thing I truly remember tbh), but I'll look into that tonight, as all other things check out. I will accept the answer as soon as I check some episodes to see if that's the one, thanks :D

Comment: @AoiTora you can mark the answer as accepted then.

Answer (score 1):

The timing may be off, but there used to be a show called *Dog City* by the Jim Henson company- mostly live-action with puppet dogs who walked upright, wore clothes, held down jobs. The main character was a cartoonist who wrote and drew a more conventionally-animated show about a dog private eye (yes you read that right), who frequently conversed back and forth with his animator.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the 2001 film *[Cats and Dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cats_%26_Dogs)*, which was release in France as "*Comme chiens et chats*"

The movie is a live-action spy action-comedy about dogs fighting against cats. The animals all talk, with their mouths and facial expressions being CGI.

According to the plot synopsis on Wikipedia, a doberman plays an important early role:

> At a local barn, a litter of Beagle puppies mock the youngest for trying to escape captivity. A Doberman Pinscher agent replaces the litter with puppy agents, failing to notice the youngest Beagle.

Answer (score -2):

Check out “VR Troopers”, specifically the character of Jeb.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you [edit] this answer to explain why you think this might be the right show though, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question?